# Corollary 1.3.2 In Problems in the Theory of Modular Forms by Murty (Formula for $r_2(n)$).

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, modular-forms

Currently I'm working through Murty's "Problems in the Theory of Modular Forms". He presents Theorem 1.3.1 as follows 
$$
\left(\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}q^{n^2}\right)^2 = 1 + 4\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{q^{4n + 1}}{1 - q^{4n + 1}} - \frac{q^{4n + 3}}{1 - q^{4n + 3}}\right)
$$
Now I've worked through the Theorem and I understand that $r_2(n)$, the number of ways that $n$ can be written as the sum of two squares, is given by the coefficient of $q^{n}$ on the right. However he then presents Corollary 1.3.2:

For $n \geq 1$, we have $r_2(n) = 4(d_1(n) - d_3(n))$ where $d_i(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$ congruent to $i$ modulo $4$.

He then says that it follows immediately from expanding the summation on the right as a power series in $q$. Now I'm currently struggling to even write the summation on the right as a power series. I don't see how to eliminate the $q$s in the denominator. Any truncation of the series I compute via Mathematica still has $q$s in the denominator. Any insight or help would be amazing, thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1 + 4\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{q^{4n + 1}}{1 - q^{4n + 1}} - \frac{q^{4n + 3}}{1 - q^{4n + 3}}\right)=1+4\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\sum_{m=1}^\infty q^{(4k+1)m}-q^{(4k+3)m}) $$ $$ =1+4 \sum_{n=1}^\infty q^n (\sum_{4k+1 | n}1 -\sum_{4k+3 | n}1 )) =1+4 \sum_{n=1}^\infty q^n (d_1(n)-d_3(n))$$
Thus with
$r_2(n) = \# \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2, a^2+b^2 = n\}$

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r_2(n) q^n = \left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}q^{n^2}\right)^2  = 1 + 4\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{q^{4n + 1}}{1 - q^{4n + 1}} - \frac{q^{4n + 3}}{1 - q^{4n + 3}}\right)$$
means $r_2(0) = 1$, $r_2(n) =4( d_1(n)-d_3(n))$

Comment: It's so obvious now, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is just the geometric series:
$$\frac{q^m}{1-q^m}=\sum_{r=1}^\infty q^{mr}.$$
Applying this to $m=4n+1$ and $4n+3$ gives
$$1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{r=1}^\infty q^{(4n+1)r}
-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{r=1}^\infty q^{(4n+3)r}$$
on the right.